# Python import restarts other imports

Tags: python, opencv

I want to create a head tracking interface for a flight simulator. I'm going to use opencv for image acquisition and processing and use vjoy to emulate the joystick (which the flight simulator can pick up & recognise).

As part of developing a toolkit of routines I have a program which highlights the brightest & darkest points in a captured frame which works well.

```
import numpy as np
import pyvjoy #works if I comment this line out
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#j = pyvjoy.VJoyDevice(1)

while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

# Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame - press q to exit',gray)

#    vjoy lines commented out 
#    xAxis=xmin*4000
#    j.data.wAxisX = 0x2000 

#    j.set_axis(HID_USAGE_X, xAxis)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works if I comment out the import of the `vjoy` library. However, when I import `vjoy` it forces a reset of the shell even though there are no other active libraries or lines. How can I prevent this?

Comment: any errorlogs you can get some info from? If so modify your question to share that info with us.

Comment: Is this really a [mcve] to reproduce the problem? (Especially the "minimal" part) Version numbers of everything involved and platform info wouldn't hurt either with an problem like this.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's on Windows, since `pyvjoy` seems to just be a simple ctypes wrapper around a DLL. I highly suspect neither OpenCV, nor Numpy have anything to do with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I slightly reformatted your question so that the problem stands out more clearly. To increase your chance of answers, you can add the information requested by the other commenters using the edit function. Additionally, what exactly do you mean by a reset of the shell?

Comment: It's to do with mixing 32 bit & 64 bit libraries. It can be quite tricky to ensure that you pick up the correct version.  I had to transfer the code to beneath the correct version. Works now (onto different problems now)